# Need an Arduino Sketch that uses digital write for a certian number of seconds

Tags: arduino

I need a simple way to run a program using digital write for a certain number of seconds.
I am driving two DC Motors. I already have my setup complete, and have driven the motors using          pause() and digitalWrite(). I will be making time measurements in milliseconds

Adjustable runtime, and would preferable have non-blocking code.

Comment: Is your question about getting a non-blocking code so you can do other things in the code while the output is set for defined time? Do you want to form pulses or the time interval may vary (constant or adjustable at run-time) ? How precisely time should be measured (is 1 ms accuracy enough)?

Comment: @Mr.Girgitt, have updated question for clarity.

Comment: In a mean time I've added a question about time accuracy.

Comment: One 1ms would be enough.

Comment: Where is your code. are using the pins from the Arduino or are  you using a shield.

Comment: I currently have no code. I don't know where to start, and several libraries that I looked at did not seem to support the purposes I needed them to. I am connected through pins(12,13,10,9)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer-driven interrupt triggering code execution which will handle the output (decrementing required time value and eventually switching off the output) or use threads.

I would suggest using threads.

Your requirement is similar to a "blinking diodes" case I described in a [different  thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501966/how-to-background-a-sleep-in-arduino/21648906#21648906)

If you replace defines setting time intervals and use variables instead you could use this code to drive outputs or simplify the whole code by using only one thread working the same way aforementioned timer interrupt would work.

If you would like to try timer interrupt-driven approach [this post](http://www.engblaze.com/microcontroller-tutorial-avr-and-arduino-timer-interrupts/) gives a good overview and examples (but you have to change OCR1A to about 16 to get overflow each 1ms) .